# Is it possible to control the order of execution of the steps in the flow in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforcedx, visual-workflow, chatter, tasks, order-of-execution

[image][image]I have created a flow in which auto-layout option is selected and I have put the steps according to my requirement, still the order of execution of the steps are not maintaining itself.

Requirement: whenever opportunity is created the two task should be created namely sourcing task and creative task at the same time, chatter should be created (through apex call action) namely sourcing and creative.

Order of execution that I want:

1. Sourcing task
2. Sourcing chatter
3. Creative task
4. Creative chatter

   Also I have put all the elements according to my requirement already
But the order of execution happening in Salesforce:

1. Sourcing task
2. Creative task
3. Sourcing chatter
4. Creative chatter
   I have tried to implement two separate flow, also tried to implement sub-flow and also by interchanging the elements but nothing worked.

Comment: Can you please share the flow screenshot? So we can see how you have defined the flow elements?

Comment: Yes, I have edited my question by adding screenshots

Comment: It would be useful to understand why the order of tasks being created vs chatter posts is actually critical. With the way transactions are managed within a Record Triggered Flow, you're going to struggle this achieve this without introducing significant complexity.

Answer (score 0):

**Flow Element: Apex Action**

**Usage:**

If a flow invokes Apex, the running user must have the corresponding Apex class assignment in their profile or permission set.

If the `invoked method creates, updates, or deletes a record, that action isn’t performed until the interview’s transaction completes`. Transactions are complete when the interview either finishes or executes a Screen, Local Action, or Pause element.

Flow Builder doesn’t display descriptions for input and output values. For details about each parameter, ask the Apex developer for more information.

Flow Builder displays Apex actions from managed packages only if the associated method is marked global.

**For more information:** https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_apex_invocable.htm&type=5

**Flow Core Action: Post to Chatter**

**Usage:**

At run time, the `Chatter post isn’t created until the interview’s transaction completes`. Transactions are complete when the interview either finishes or executes a Screen, Local Action, or Pause element.

**For more information:** https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_actions_chatter.htm&type=5

Comment: so what should I do, my requirement is like that, is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: You can create two different flows for this. in one flow you can add action for the Sourcing and in another one add action for the Creative. The flow name should be alphabetically so run accordingly.

Flows with the same trigger (before- or after-save) on the same object with trigger order values from 1 to 1,000 run in ascending order (1, 2, 3, and so on). Multiple flows with the same trigger order value run in alphabetical order based on the flows’ API names.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_concepts_trigger_guidelines.htm&type=5

Comment: I have tried creating two different flow by naming as Sourcing task flow and Sourcing task flow 2, but still the order of execution is same as previously